# Pay for Cognito Forms annually instead of monthly

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any way to pay yearly instead of monthly? The web page that shows up for payment only offers a monthly option, but my company requires a 1 time yearly payment for subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can see, you may be able to change your billing period once you complete the registration.

Try tweeting them, or looking for a sales email or phone number, then you can ask them if they will take a yearly payment.

their twitter handle is @cognitoforms.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Although we do not currently have a way to sign up for a yearly plan, this is currently being worked on and we hope to have it ready in the next month. You can submit a [help ticket](http://help.cognitoforms.com/request-help) requesting to sign up for a years worth of a specific plan and we will be happy to assist setting this up.

Answer (score 1):

You can now prepay annually or for a specific number of months:

https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing#prepay

Our prepayment calculator makes it easy to prepay based on the number of months, number of users, and your desired plan.  Prepayments are discounted up to 20% and do not lock you in to a specific plan, so you can make changes at any time.

[image]